# Automatic mounting in /run/media instead of /media

Tags: mount, udev, udisks

When I (manually) mount my crypted document partition on ubuntu 19/04, it is mounted on /media. When I'm in Fedora, it's mounted on /run/media.

I would like udisks2 to mount it on /run/media, as it should be, so I made a udev rules like this :

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-udisk2.rules 

# UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
# ==1: mount filesystem to a shared directory (/media/VolumeName)
# ==0: mount filesystem to a private directory (/run/media/$USER/VolumeName)
# See udisks(8)
ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem|other|crypto", ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="0"
```

But, even after reboot, the document parition is still mounted on /media. Can someone help me to mount it on /run/media ?

Answer (score 5):

Well, it is a source building option as mentioned by [this commit](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/commit/ae2a5ff1e49ae924605502ace170eb831e9c38e4) when it was introduced.

> **Support mounting in /media for FHS compatibility**
>
> Add `--enable-fhs-media` configure option to mount in `/media` instead of
>   `/run/media`, for FHS compliance and backwards compatibility.

Options I could think of:

- Make a symlink
- Bind mount
- Rebuild the package

Comment: Can it be configured somewhere in configuration file or I must re-compile the package?

Comment: @Anwar, Unfortunately, that configuration is compile time option. So you have to recompile if you want change it without workarounds.

Comment: Yes. I recompiled and worked accordingly