# Change removable devices mount point

Tags: mount

I have two dirfferent linux systems on my PCs, which use the same external drive in order to store KdenLive projects. First one is Ubuntu, the second one is Arch. My mount point on Ubuntu is `/media/[user]/[drive]`, but on Arch it is `/run/media/[user]/[drive]`. So how can I change my mount point on Ubuntu for all of the removable devices to `/run/media/[user]/[drive]`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140662/automatic-mounting-in-run-media-instead-of-media

Comment: The easiest indeed will be to check if a symlink /run/media/[user] that points to /media/user on your the Ubuntu system does the trick.